# Can I build my level 6 Ranger so that his bow shots never miss?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, ranged-attack

Is it possible for me to make my Human ranger like Hawkeye, to where (1) I never miss and (2) I can use my Sharpshooter ability every shot. I'm currently a level 6 ranger.

I want it so that the only reason for rolling the d20 is to see if my bow breaks.

My DM doesn't have any other punishments when I roll a 1, so when I roll a 1 my bow can break.

Comment: And with that out of the way I'll repeat and expand LizWeir's welcome: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Are you positive you’re playing DnD 5e?

Comment: Why would rolling a d20 ever result in a broken bow.

Comment: And what level are you/when you want to be able to do this?

Comment: Well my DM doesn't have any other punishments when I roll a 1 oh and I'm level 6 now

Comment: Liam, your DM is applying a non rule to the game.  there is no 'break weapon' rule on a 1 unless the DM is applying a particular home brew rule.  Please review chapter 9 and discuss with your DM.  Do you own a copy of the players handbook?

Comment: Here are the [basic rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) for free if you do not have the PHB.

Comment: A bow break on a 1 is a particularly harsh rule, and just got worse for you when you hit level 6. Attacking twice per turn now, with he average combat lasting 3 turns is 6 shots per combat. That means you break a bow every 3-4 combats and the guidelines suggest 8 combats a day. Breaking 2 bows a day is pretty careless for a particularly strong young and clumsy child, nevermind a skilled adventuring ranger whose life depends on his bow skills.

Comment: Where do I read that at 6th level I get 2 attacks? I printed out all the pages referring to ranger in the PHB and didn't see that anywhere

Comment: My mistake, is it at 5th, the Extra Attack feature: Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Answer (score 5):

## High attack bonuses are possible

This is dependent on level and magic items. It is also dependent on the target's AC. A rather high modifier can be obtained with +6 proficiency, +5 dexterity, archery fighting style, a +3 bow, +3 ammunition, and ioun stone of mastery for a total of +20, making a attack roll result of at least 22 (a 1 misses anyway, *vide Supra*), sufficient for AC 17 with Sharpshooter. (But see note below). Further increases can be achieved using epic boons. Other bonuses such as bardic inspiration are also useful, but those rely on limited resources running contrary to the desire to *always* hit.

The maximum possible modifier on your current level is of course lower, even with appropriate magic items (which are probably difficult to come by, especially so at level 6). With +3 proficiency and +4 Dex you can have only +16 with the calculation above.

## In 5e missing is always possible

Like a rolled natural 20 will always hit, a natural 1 will always miss. Therefore, even with a very high modifier, there is a 5% miss chance. Of course there are features which allow rerolls. For example the Halfling's Lucky allows rerolling a 1 once. This with a very high modifier would mean that only one in four hundred attacks would miss. It is not a human however and it does not let you avoid rolling entirely. [Incidentally, a halfling also cannot efficiently use a longbow.] There a ways to avoid the attack roll entirely, such as the clockwork amulet or the rogue's stroke of luck. These cannot be used consistently however.

Also, in 5e, there are no basic rules which would make a bow break.

Comment: That linked question isn't a catalogue of ways to increase to hit modifier, it's a set of compatible ones which stack to +100 (average; because why not?). You should maybe state how high a modifier you need before you basically always hit and then give at least an overview of how to get there. (And remember Sharpshooter when doing those considerations.)

Comment: He finally told us the ranger's level.  6th.  Please adjust the answer to apply that information.

Comment: I am missing something. +6 proef +5 dex + 2 archery +3 bow +3 ammunition + 1 mastery = +20. I am missing a +3 here somewhere (maybe you are including Oil of Sharpness?). It is also extremely unlikely that a 6th level character has access to all of those magic items, we need clarification for that from the question. Overall, the question is very unclear and trying to answer that can only lead to an answer based on guesses.

Comment: Looks like I miscalculated. I did state that obtaining the items was not easy. But I can make that more clear.